# Promise.all returning undefined value

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, promise

I have a function that makes several requests with `request-promise` to a server:

```
query = function(entity) {
  //some SPARQL request here with the "entity" parameter
  rp(url)
  .then(function(res) {
    console.log(res)
    return new Promise(resolve => res)
  })
  .catch(function(err) {
    console.log("error")
  })
}

async function musicData() {
  data = [1,2,3,4]

  var queries = data.map(query)

  var results = await Promise.all(queries)

  return results
}

musicData()
.then(function(resp) {
  console.log(resp);
})
.catch(function(err) {
  console.log("err")
})
```

I can't figure out why does `musicData()` returns an array of `undefined` values. How can I make it return the promises considering that `console.log(res)` in `query()` logs the correct response?

Comment: Change query function to  query = async function($... then try again :)

Comment: @Kai That wouldn't help.

Comment: I doubt `return new Promise(resolve => res)` does return anything at all

Comment: @Bergi It returns a promise that never resolves.

Comment: @JLRishe Yeah, that's what I meant. So `musicData()` should never resolve to an array of anything.

Comment: @Bergi Based on the above code, `data.map(query)` evaluates to an array of four `undefined`s, so `await Promise.all(queries)` evaluates to an array of four `undefined`s. So it makes sense that `musicData()` resolves to an array of `undefined`. `new Promise(resolve => res)` is definitely bonkers, though.

Comment: you can try `return Promise.resolve(res)` :);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not returning anything from `query`, so no promise gets returned to the mapping function, so `queries` ends up as an array of `undefined`s. You also shouldn't `return new Promise` inside a `then` - just return the value you want to be consumed later. Change to:

```
const query = function(entity) {
  return rp(url)
    .then(function(res) {
       console.log(res);
       return res;
     })
     // ...
```

(take care not to implicitly create global variables)

Answer (score 0):

The `query` function has no `return` statement, so it will always return `undefined`.

`var queries = data.map(query)` will therefore map the data to an array of `undefined` values.

You need to edit `query` so it **returns a Promise**.